# C++ main file has undeclared identifier that's declared in the header file (Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, undeclared-identifier

Xcode states that in my main file, "stdDev" is an undeclared identifier but it's been declared in the header file. I'm completely burnt how to fix this. I would appreciate some assistance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include "Person.hpp"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
Person personRob("Rob", 95);
Person personBob("Bob", 89);
Person personGob("Gob", 99);

Person personArray[] = {personRob, personBob, personGob};

Person whole_class;

cout << "Standard deviation is: " << stdDev /* where Xcode is saying that stdDev is an undeclared identifier */ << endl;

return 0;
}
```

person.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef PERSON_HPP
#define PERSON_HPP

class Person

{

private:

    std::string name;
    double age;

public:
    Person(std::string = " ", double = 0.0);
    std::string getName();
    double getAge();
    double stdDev(Person personArray[], int size);

 };

 #endif
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's wrong without seeing the contents of Person.hpp.

Comment: I added the header file

Comment: `stdDev` is a method. It need to be invoked on an instance of `Person`. Something like `cout << "Standard deviation is: " << whole_class.stdDev(more missing stuff goes here) << endl;` Otherwise the compiler thinks you have some variable out there named `stdDev` that it can't find.

Comment: Where is `stdDev` defined? there's a method with this name, but you probably don't mean that, and if you do - you need to go back to the basics.

Answer (score 1):

`stdDev` is declared as a non-static member function. In order to use it, you need to call it on an object with the appropriate arguments, such as:

```
std::cout << whole_class.stdDev(personArray, 3)
```

That's the syntactic fix.

However, it does sound like a good fit for a member function. From the name of the function, it appears that you intend to compute the standard deviation of the ages of the list of `Person`s in the array.

Make it a non-member function.

Then, you can use it as:

```
std::cout << stdDev(personArray, 3)
```